# Suggestion for a power on/off system circuits

Tags: power

In my last projects, I've used a usefull circuit that I found on the web for power on/off my electronic systems:

[image]

It works very well: I connect the output to the enable pin of the main voltage regulator so to turn on the system you have to press the buton and to turn off hold the button for abount 3/4 seconds.
Now I want that the microcontroller of the system shuts down properly some peripherals before the whole turning off.

Do you have any suggestion to modify this circuit or another one for this scope?

Comment: What behaviors do you want?

Comment: @dannyf Turn on: simply push the button. Turn off: hold the button for about 3 seconds, but the microcontroller must know the event and shut down someone peripheric IC before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There's a chip for this job

If you're OK with a single chip solution and can work with SMT ICs, I'd use a [LTC2951](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/295112fb.pdf).  It needs a minimum of external components; namely, a couple of ceramic caps and a pull-up for the interrupt pin, as well as the pushbutton of course.  It also has a wide supply voltage range, even wider than the 4000 series CMOS used in the circuit you posted.

Comment: Nice part, but pricey (over $4 in singles).

Comment: Yes, is a good component but very expensive. Do you know one more cheaper?

Comment: @thoraz -- not with the package + supply voltage range combo

Comment: I have found the STM6600 family chip that seem to be very good.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the modification I would do: -

[image]

When the MCU powers up, it takes the OUT pin low and starts monitoring the IN pin. If the IN pin goes low then this means the button is pressed and, if the MCU has completed its task of shutting down peripherals it keeps OUT low. If it hasn't completed the task it takes OUT high to prevent the button being held for 3 seconds turning the system off.

Optional extra using the IN pin as an OUT pin - at any time the MCU can start the turn off process by activating this pin low.

If you really wanted to be clever you could get rid of the OUT pin and have the push-button connected back to 0 volts but via a (say) 1 kohm resistor. You continue to monitor IN until it goes low then, if the MCU is not ready to shut-down, you can turn the IN into an OUT pin and hold that node high until the MCU is ready to turn off.

This saves an IO pin.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Thanks. I will use it in the future.